# Copying from std container frm arbitrary source object

Tags: c++, containers, std

I created a read only iterator which allows me to use it in a for loop more conveniently then with the std iterators, similar to what boost does with the FOREACH (not as good but good enough :))

Now it looks like this:

```
for(ReadOnylIterator<MyClass *> class = parent.getIterator(); class.end(); ++class)
   class->function();
```

The problem that I have now is, that I must implement a function on the parent which returns the iterator. Since the std containers have all the same syntax, I was wondering if it is possible to define a copy constructor/assignment operator on the Iterator that accepts any of the std:: containers and creates the copy itself, instead of requiring the class to return it.

Of course I want to avoid having to define all of them myself like as there are lots of them:

```
ReadOnlyIterator<T> &operator=(std::list<T> const &v)
ReadOnlyIterator<T> &operator=(std::vector<T> const &v)
...
```

Is there a way to do this? When I look at the source of the vector I don't see a common base class, so I think it might not be posssible.

I don't understnad why the assignment operator doesn't work.

In my code I test it like this:

```
std::vector<SimpleClass *>t;
ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> &it = t;
```

And I get

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'ReadOnlyIterator<T> &'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Container>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, typename Container::value_type>::value, ReadOnlyIterator<T>&>::type operator= (const Container &v);
```

The above code uses C++11. If you don't have access to that, you could use the equivalent functionality from Boost.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/X27Qo0)

---

In case you can use neither C++11 nor Boost, you can code the necessary classes yourself:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template <bool, typename>
struct enable_if
{};

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

To use this in a constructor, define it like this:

```
template <typename Container>
ReadOnlyIterator(const Container &v, typename enable_if<is_same<T, typename Container::value_type>::value, void>::type * = 0) {}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/k3upiR)

Comment: I don't have C11 available and also can not use boost. :(

Comment: @Devolus Well, you can always look into Boost (or just google SFINAE) and code the relevant part yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my understanding of this template stuff is really limited I hate to admit. I added your changes to my code, ut I still get the error. I updated my question and added the error that I get. Somehow this assignment operator doesn't work and I don't understand why. I'm also not sure how to use this Container type that you gave me. I tried to get it working with at least on container, but even that doesn't work.

Comment: I just noticed this live example from you and now it works. :) THANKS!

Comment: @Devolus Notice that `ReadOnlyInterator<T> i = whatever;` is not *assignment,* it's *initialisation,* and so it invokes a constructor, **not** `operator=`. You'll have to do the same thing for a constructor as well. There's no return type, so you'll have to use `enable_if` in a parameter (with a default argument).

Comment: could you show me how this is done? I'v been trying to find a solution but I don't get it. this template syntax is driving me crazy. :(

Comment: @Devolus I've edited the answer and the second Ideone example.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't seem to work. Shall I open a new question with that?

Comment: @Devolus A new question would probably be better. Put a complete minimal example in it, along with the complete error message you get.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626840/template-class-constructor-not-working

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but no, this is not possible given that the containers don't have common base classes. You'll have to write an operator for each container, Sad news !

Although if the behavior of the operator functions is always the same, you could just make a macro that contains the code, and copy paste it for every container type ^_^