# Template class constructor not working

Tags: c++, templates

From my other question here [Copying from std container frm arbitrary source object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622398/copying-from-std-container-frm-arbitrary-source-object/16622897?noredirect=1#comment23907051_16622897) I managed to get the template almost working under MSVC. Unfortunately the compiler crashes with the newest addtion of adding a constructor to accept all kind of std containers, and my real project is in gcc anyway. Now when I use this template in gcc, I get several errors I don't know how to resolve.

```
template <class T> class ReadOnlyIterator
{
public:
    template <typename V, typename U>
    struct is_same
    {
        enum { value = 0 };
    };

    template <typename V>
    struct is_same<V, V>
    {
        enum { value = 1 };
    };

    template <bool, typename>
    struct enable_if
    {};

    template <typename V>
    struct enable_if<true, V>
    {
        typedef V type;
    };

template <typename Container>
    typename enable_if<
    is_same<T, typename Container::value_type>::value, ReadOnlyIterator<T>&>::type operator= (const Container &v)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename Container>
    ReadOnlyIterator(const Container &v, typename enable_if<is_same<T, typename Container::value_type>::value, void>::type * = 0)
    {
        mVector = v;
        mBegin = mVector.begin();
    }
};
```

My goal was to allow assignments like this:

```
std::vector<SimpleClass *>v;
std::list<SimpleClass *>l;
ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> t0 = v;
ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> &t1 = v;
ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> t2 = ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *>(v);
ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> t3 = l;

t0 = v;
t0 = l;
```

I updated the code above and reverted the wrong changes I applied. So now I only get the original problem I tried to fix:

```
ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> &t1 = v;
```

leads to:

```
invalid initialization of reference of type 'ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass*>&' from expression of type 'std::vector<SimpleClass*, std::allocator<SimpleClass*> >'
```

Comment: Note that in your previous question, I used `struct` instead of `class` for the helpers (`struct` has public access by default, `class` has private), and that I made them namespace-scope, not nested in the `ReadOnlyIterator`.

Comment: OK. I changed it back, but it still doesn't work as I get the same errors as above.

Comment: See leemes' answer. You could have at least copied my previous answer properly.

Comment: Also please indicate which lines give you the errors.

Comment: I don't understand your constructor. First, why does it have yet another template parameter? Second, why do you access member variables which we don't see? Please show us them. Third, why is the assignment operator not doing *anything* (but returning a reference)?

Comment: @leemes These come from the prior question (which I understood wants to wrap an *arbitrary* container's iterator) and my answer (where the declaration of `op=` was important, not the body, so I put the minimal working thing there).

Comment: @Angew, sorry for the changes, I forgot to revert them, as I tried to fix the last issue I had. I updated the code now and it reflects the results from the last questions from you, with the one error I still get.

Comment: "The compiler crashes" means that you get a "The application stopped responding" message from Windows, or an "Internal Compiler Error" message in your log.  Is that true?  Or is the compiler simply rejecting your code?  That is not a crash, that is the compiler doing exactly what it is supposed to (reporting problems in your code).

Comment: I got an internal compiler error. If the code is wron I would expect the compiler to throw some error at me, not telling me that it has an internal error.

Comment: For this "original error you tried to fix," see my answer to this question (the first parahraph thereof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, if you write a template class within another template class, you have to give the template parameters different names:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
struct is_same<U, V>
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};
```

In the specialization of `is_same`, you have to use the *same types* when specifying the specialized class name (you can also name it `U`, but use the same name on all three places: in the template parameter list as well as in the specialized class name):

```
template <typename V>
struct is_same<V, V>
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you should make these helper-classes `struct` instead of `class`; then you don't have to write `public:`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the error comes from the second declaration, which is simply illegal. You're creating a reference to non-const `ReadOnlyIterator`, so you cannot initialise this with a temporary (such as one created by the converting constructor). If you need a reference, use a reference to `const`. But you probably don't need one.

The third declaration:

```
ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> t2(v) = v;
```

is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, It should have been ` ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *> t2 = ReadOnlyIterator<SimpleClass *>(v);` and I fixed it in the question.